# Laravel 5 TokenMismatchException on PHP 5.6.9

Tags: php, laravel-5, csrf

Post requests work fine running Laravel 5 app on PHP 5.4. Post requests on the **same app** running on PHP **5.6.9** generate:

> TokenMismatchException VerifyCsrfToken.php on line 46

This happens on every post request on both WAMP and IIS. Happens using database sessions and file sessions. Did a full reinstall and also tried all suggestions made here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/keep-getting-tokenmismatchexception-verifycsrftokenphp-on-line-46?page=2. Folks are disabling the Csrf middleware as a fix, but that is not a viable solution. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would be tempted to debug the `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` and before `return parent::handle($request, $next);` do something like: `dd([ Input::all() , Session::all() ])` - test the `_token` in session matches that of `_token` in your input.

Comment: I changed the cookie/session cache engine in the `.env`. `CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I realized this was only happening in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox, it led me to the fix. The app was using AddThis share buttons and the javascript was adding an iframe to the pages. This issue is resolved by adding a P3P header to the VerifyCsrfToken Middleware. Hope this saves somebody the hours I lost.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (last(explode('\\',get_class($response))) != 'RedirectResponse') {
            $response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: just took few hours likely 4 5 :/ :3

Comment: It saved me lot of time

Comment: This is the only solution which works in the ocean of ridiculous "add csrf_field" answers on the net. Thanks you very much for your working solution.

Comment: Finally an answer that works! Thank you! I have no idea why this works, but it does the trick not only on Chrome, but Firefox, too.

Answer (score 0):

put `<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` so token is always available and use that with your AJAX request:
ex:

```
var csrftoken =  (function() {
var metas = window.document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for(var i=0 ; i < metas.length ; i++) {
    if ( metas[i].name === "csrf-token") {
        return  metas[i].content;
    }
}})();
```

Comment: this could be oneline with jquery

Comment: yes it could, something like `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

just add `{{ csrf_field() }}` to your form block and it will save you lot of time

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" class="form-signin">
{{ csrf_field() }}
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, who is facing this issue in spite of adding `{{ csrf_field() }}` in the `form` field and even by adding this in the head tag
 `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

The issue is with writing in the storage because of not adding your current user on Linux in the right group. Make sure to add your current user to `www-data` group.
Write this command

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /path/to/laravel-folder
```

Make sure to give right permission to storage folder as well in the laravel app.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/laravel-folder/storage
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue and I could solve it by just adding the following package on top:
**"Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,"**

[image]