# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53 (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I read some questions about this problem, and I use this input in my form:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

But this not works, when I send my form the TokenMismatchException appears in my screen.

This is my complete form, I don´t want use web controllers to post, I want post in self file.

```
<form method="POST" action="order.php" id="formcontacto">
                        <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje"></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="FUNCTION" id="FUNCTION" value="creaincid" />
                        <button id="btn-enviar" class="btn" type="button" onclick="envia();">Enviar</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next_url" value="{{ $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    </form>
```

Comment: Where is your submit button ? Are you submitting the form via AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this myself and is normally something quite simple that has been over looked.

First off if you are using a blade template try adding to your template

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

More information - http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

This can also be an issue with with config/session.php check there isn't an issue with the domain entered here.

If neither of these address the issue you may need to create a middleware

An excellent answer can be found here:
[Laravel 5 TokenMismatchException on PHP 5.6.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490821/laravel-5-tokenmismatchexception-on-php-5-6-9/30508294#30508294)