# Laravel 5.2 ajax POST 403

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm having some issues with Laravel 5.2 when I do an ajax POST I get a 403 error

1. Ajax POST request

   ```
   $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },

            data: {category_id:category_id,  _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            url: '/admin/gallery/create/ajax',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('#object').empty();
                $('#object').append(data);
            },
            error: function(msg)
            {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
   ```
2. Route

   ```
   Route::post('admin/gallery/create/ajax',           ['as' => 'gallery.ajax',    'uses' => 'GalleryController@getObject']);
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
   public function getObject(Request $request){
        $data = array();
        if($request->category_id == 'users'){
            $allItems = User::all();
            foreach ($allItems as $key => $item) {
                $data += array($key=>'<option value="'.$item['name'].'">'.$item['name'].'</option>');
            }
        }
        if($request->category_id == 'authors'){
            $allItems = Author::all();
            foreach ($allItems as $key => $item) {
                $data += array($key=>'<option value="'.$item['name'].'">'.$item['name'].'</option>');
            }
        }
        if($request->category_id == 'galleries'){
            $allItems = Gallery::all();
            foreach ($allItems as $key => $item) {
                $data += array($key=>'<option value="'.$item['name'].'">'.$item['name'].'</option>');
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
   ```
4. result

   ```
   POST  403 (Forbidden)
   ```
5. but with route:

   ```
   Route::post  ('admin/gallery/create/ajax', function(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request){
      if (Session::token() == Request::header('x-csrf-token'))
      {
          echo $request->category_id;
      } else {
          return 'ERROR';
      }
   });
   ```
6. result

   [request done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi1SU.jpg)
7. with GET all work fine

   ```
   $.ajax({
       headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       },
       data: {category_id:category_id},
       url: '/admin/gallery/create/ajax/',
       method: 'get',
       success: function(data)
       {
          $('#object').empty();
          $('#object').append(data);
       },
       error: function(msg)
       {
          console.log(msg);// если ошибка, то можно посмотреть в консоле
       }
   });
   ```

   ROUTE GET

   ```
    Route::get      ('/admin/gallery/create/ajax/',         ['as' => 'gallery.ajax',    'uses' => 'GalleryController@getObject']);
   ```

8. [GET RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuGDv.jpg)
9. **Need help with AJAX POST**

Comment: Can you show what you have in routes file. Because code seems to be correct may be you have same route and it is overriding by the other .

Comment: test project
https://github.com/gryshkoevgeniy/bookslaravel.git

only routes:
https://github.com/gryshkoevgeniy/bookslaravel/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php

Comment: functions.js with GET $ POST requests
https://github.com/gryshkoevgeniy/bookslaravel/blob/master/public/js/functions.js

Comment: According to me what you have created with the post request is correct. But just comment the get route when you are using the post route and the javascript function with get method too.

Comment: Route::any     ('admin/gallery/create/ajax',           ['as' => 'gallery.ajax',    'uses' => 'GalleryController@getObject']);

with
url: '/admin/gallery/create/ajax',
= 403 (Forbidden)
with 
url: 'admin/gallery/create/ajax',
=
404 (Not Found)

all tested with GET route = //Route::get

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added your route to the `web` middleware group. Otherwise the token will not be verified.

The `web` middleware group looks like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
```

As you can see it verifies the token in `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`.

So in your `routes.php` file, add the middleware group as the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Your route goes here
});
```

Comment: You can check the link in comment middleware is already there.

Comment: Git:
https://github.com/gryshkoevgeniy/bookslaravel

Git for Kernel
https://github.com/gryshkoevgeniy/bookslaravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Answer (score 0):

Right Answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30508294/5908145

Now work with this params:

```
Route::post     ('/admin/gallery/create/ajax',           ['as' => 'gallery.ajax',    'uses' => 'GalleryController@getObject']);

$.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: {category_id:category_id,  _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            url: '/admin/gallery/create/ajax',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('#object').empty();
                $('#object').append(data);
            },
            error: function(msg)
            {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
```

VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
    $response = $next($request);

    if (last(explode('\\',get_class($response))) != 'RedirectResponse') {
        $response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    }

    return $response;
}
```

thx for all!